# How to create a download link to access an object inside the Google memcache

Tags: html, google-app-engine, memcached

I have an application running inside the Google App Engine. This application creates entrys inside the memcache and I want to access each entry as a file via a download link. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this to handle swf-files stored in as blobs. You should easily be able to modify it to suit your needs and type of files.

```
class SwfHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    query = cgi.FieldStorage()
    swf = BlobStorage.get_by_id(int(query.getvalue('id')))

    if swf:
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-shockwave-flash'
        self.response.out.write(swf.fileData)
    else:
        self.error(404)   

## add "('/swfhandler/', SwfHandler)" to your application :
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/swfhandler/', SwfHandler), ****)
```

I request the file with: /swfhandler/?id=12

Answer (score 3):

You need to define your own handler, which takes the key as part of the URL, or a query string, and returns the appropriate object from memcache.

Remember that memcache is intended to be a *cache*, not a reliable storage mechanism, so you should have some way to retrieve an object even if it's been evicted from the cache.

Comment: The application is used to generate keypairs and the secret key is put into the memcache with a time to live of approx. 1 minute. I want the data to be erased automatically after some time. After the keypair is generated, the user is relocated to a page that shows the secret key and I want to have a link where I can download it via a single click.

Comment: Because memcache is a cache, though, the data could be evicted before the user accesses it. The time to live is an upper bound, not a restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, it should be as simple as outputting appropriate headers before outputting the entry contents you fetched.